# Can I share a one-to-one entity using @MapsId for multiple parents using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, entity-relationship

I've read some best practices about how to map `@OneToOne` relationships using `@MapsId`

[Like this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

And I'm wondering, will it work if the entity is "shared" ?

eg...

```
Employee has Address OneToOne...
Department has Address OneToOne...
```

Can we here use the same approach? or The EMPLOYEES and DEPARTMENTS tables shall have fk_address_id ?

Should I treat this through a interface `HasAddress`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work, but the sharing is between the Parent and the Child, not across Parents. So, the `Employee` will use its own `Address` row while the `Department` will use a different row.

But, this is not an `@OneToOne` relationship if you want to share it. It's a `@ManyToOne` because the `Address` can be the Parent and the `Employee` and `Department` are the Child entities. In this case, both the `Employee` and the `Department` will use an FK column to the `Address` PK.

So, it is a many-to-one association if you want to share the `Address` row. If you don't, then you can use one-to-one with `@MapsId` on the `Address` entity and `mappedBy` on `Department` and `Employee`.

Comment: Maybe the right wording here will be the 'shared' `TABLE`. Because `Employee` and `Department` can manage its own `Address`.

Comment: So in this case I have to put `@MapsId` with `@OneToOne` in `Employee` and `Department` class over the field of type `Address` right?

Comment: Nope. It is a many-to-one association if you want to share the Address row. If you don't, then you can use one-to-one with Maps on the Address entity and mappedBy on Department and Employee.